# Can we add .sql file in resource & access the database , tables

Tags: android

I am able to create database , tables , insert data & retrieve by using Android code .

I came to know that in iPhone , there is any option of creating database , table using both code & UI & we can add the sql file in the resource folder . 
It will help us by reducing the time taken in creating the database & tables when the application is run.

Is the same functionality of adding a predefined .sql file to the resource file possible ?